# Weird overload resolution with variadic function templates

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, overload-resolution

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Args>
void f(int a, int b, Args... args) { 
    std::cout << b << '\n';
    f(a, args...);
}
void f(int, int b) {
    std::cout << b << '\n';     
}

int main() {
  f(1, 2);
  //f(1, 2, 3);
}
```

While `f(1, 2)` compiles, `f(1, 2, 3)` does not. From the error message produced by the compiler, I see that `f<>` is being instantiated somehow. Within the instantiation, the call `f(a)` is made and thus the error. What makes the compiler not to use `f(int, int)` but try to instantiate `f<>(int, int)` during the process of parsing the call `f(1, 2, 3)`?

Comment: Reorder the decls. I.e. put your overload *first*, then your template, and try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the variadic function template `f()`, the `f` in the recursive call is a dependent name due to [temp.dep], emphasis mine:

> In an expression of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> postfix-expression ( expression-listopt)
> ```
>
> where the *postfix-expression* is an *unqualified-id*, the *unqualified-id* denotes a dependent name if
>   (1.1) — any of the expressions in the *expression-list* is **a pack expansion** (14.5.3),

And, according to [temp.dep.res], emphasis mine:

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>   (1.1) — Declarations that are visible at the **point of definition** of the template.
>   (1.2) — Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the
>   instantiation context (14.6.4.1) and from the definition context.

There is only one declaration of `f` that is visible at the point of definition of `template <typename... Args> void f(int, int, Args...)` and that is itself. The second point doesn't apply here because all of your arguments are `int`s and there's no associated namespaces for fundamental types. Since that function template cannot be called with a single argument, you get a compile error.

The solution is to restructure your code so that your base case is visible at the point of definition, that is:

```
// this can be just the declaration
void f(int, int ) { /* ... */ } 

template <typename... Args>
void f(int a, int b, Args... args) 
{ 
    std::cout << b << '\n';
    f(a, args...); // now this will call f(int, int) 
                   // if sizeof...(Args) == 1
}
```

An example in which (1.2) applies would be the following:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename A, typename... Args>
void f(A a, int b, Args... args) { 
    std::cout << b << '\n';
    f(a, args...);
}

template <typename A>
void f(A a, int b) {
    std::cout << b << '\n';     
}

struct bar {};

int main() {
    //f(1,2,3);     // still doesn't compile, same reasoning
    f(bar{}, 2, 3); // OK. bar is in the global namespace, so declarations
                    // from the global namespace in both instantiation 
                    // and definition context are considered, which includes
                    // the second `f`.
}
```

Comment: Or, forward declare `void f(int,int)`.

Comment: I just thought the compiler should parse the prototypes first and then the definitions, so that all declarations are visible when parsing the definitions.